# How did Leia arrive on Tatooine in Return of The Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

Did she come with Luke? Isn't the X-wing only built for one?

Comment: No time to look it up, but in a deleted scene they show after the rescue that the X-Wing and he Millenium Falcon where both parked in the desert. So I think she arrived with the Falcon.

Comment: Yes, i know that scene, but in the movie C-3PO said: " Lando Calrissian and poor Chewbacca never returned from this awful place". This make me think that Leia and C-3PO didn't came in the Falcon.

Comment: @GustavoSanchez Sounds like a plot hole to me. Unless, Lando, Chewie and Leia all went off somewhere else to do the stuff for their plan and only Leia came back to the Luke & Droids camp. Lando went to Jabba's Palace, then Leia came back (to somewhere) to pick up Chewie and execute their part of the plan. So, I think all came on the Falcon.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer, this is not even remotely a plot hole. Just because they all leave there with the Falcon (safe Luke) does not imply they all came there together. She could have hired another ship. It's not spelled out in the movie 'cos it simply does not matter for the story.

Comment: @Ghanima I never said they did. I'm just trying for an explanation that sticks with with limited limited information. The "plot hole" is talking about Lando and Chewie not returning from this awful place. It's been established 3PO is talking about Jabba's Palace. But Chewie ain't there yet. Lando 1st, Droids 2nd, Leia/Chewie 3rd, Luke 4th.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer, ah, that. Yes, that's right. Thanks :)

Comment: [what's a plot hole?](http://imgur.com/gallery/L7zDu)

Answer (score 18):

Presumably, she arrived in the Millenium Falcon, which is how she leaves Tatooine with the rest of the group.

From [the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Return-of-the-Jedi.html)

> 44A  EXT SPACE ABOVE TATOOINE
>
> The desolate yellow planet fills the screen, Luke's X-wing appears and 
>   peels off to the left. A moment later, the FALCON appears as a dot and 
>   grows huge, to roar directly over the CAMERA.
>
> 45   INT X-WING - COCKPIT
>
> Luke is at the controls, with Artoo attached behind him outside the 
>   canopy. Luke speaks into his comlink to the others, in the MILLENNIUM 
>   FALCON.

The deleted Sandstorm scene at roughly [2:50 into this video](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xsb6j9_star-wars-episode-vi-deleted-scenes-tatooine-sandstorm_shortfilms) shows the Falcon parked somewhere on Tatooine, so we know they didn't shuttle up to the ship elsewhere.

Comment: There is the disconnect between Empire and Jedi. At the end of V Lando and Chewie depart in the Falcon. But Lando is already in Jabba's Palace, whereas Chewie arrived with Leia. I know there are books that covered the interregnum, but it's easy to get confused about exactly what happened.

Comment: Ok, but in the movie C-3PO said: " Lando Calrissian and poor Chewbacca never returned from this awful place". This make me think that Leia and C-3PO didn't come in the Falcon.

Comment: He's referring to Jabba's Palace, not Tatooine. They all come to Tatooine together, Lando infiltrates while the others hang out at the cantina and spa, and then phase 2 of the plan begins when the droids go to Jabba's.

Comment: Presumably Lando returned the falcon to Leia after Han was located, or Lando sent a message to Leia and she arrived by private transport. Either that or she road in Luke's lap the hole way... awkward!

Comment: @MarkRogers The *hole* way? O.O awkward indeed.

Comment: Ha, I need to remember to actually check my own spelling.

Comment: At the end of *Empire*, Lando says they will "find Han". One explanation is that Lando and Chewie found out that Boba Fett had taken Han to Jabba and then returned to Luke (now fully recovered) and Leia to come up with a plan to rescue Han. A big mystery brought up by this theory is with Luke and Leia stuck together with nothing to do right after having a force connection over a long distance in the sky of Bespin, what kept them from figuring out they might be related, or instead from, uhhh... "acting inappropriately"?

Comment: @ToddWilcox Leia had already declared her love for Han, even though she was feeling it right from the beginning of EV - she only kissed Luke to make Han jealous. What is unfortunate is Luke's reaction. What's funny is R2D2's reaction since he knows who they both are....

Comment: They deleted the sandstorm scene? I should strangle Darude editors who did that!

Comment: Probably worth including [this comment of yours](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109998/how-did-leia-arrive-on-tatooine-in-return-of-the-jedi#comment261096_109999) into the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: @GustavoSanchez did you just base your analysis on what C3PO said? lol imo they all (sans Luke) arrived via the Falcon, then they formed a plan for Lando and Chewbacca to infiltrate the palace first before the more well-known and thus less conspicuous Leia (being a former Senator after all) makes her move. Every single Rebel in history has always left C3PO out of the loop and sometimes even intentionally acted something in front of him because of how easily he leaks intel lol

Answer (score 3):

According to original Lucas notes, they arrived on a Falcon.

> Perhaps the earliest outline for Jedi, written on a single page, has the droids landing on Tatooine and looking for Luke and Leia in a spaceport, but finding no one. **A sentence reads, “Angry landlord takes Falcon?”** The droids find them at an inn, where Luke and Leia have to decide between the rebellion and saving Han, which creates a “time lock”—that is, a device to create suspense in the film, a due date (*The Making of ROTJ, by J.W. Rinzler*)

The fact that Luke and Leia arrived together kept into further drafts (but doesn't specify it was on Falcon):

> **RETURN OF THE JEDI, BY L. KASDAN AND G. LUCAS, NOVEMBER 1, 1981—REVISED SECOND DRAFT SUMMARY**
>
> Commander Skywalker and Princess Leia have made their way to the Tatooine system in an attempt to rescue their friend Han Solo from the clutches of the vile gangster, Jabba the Hutt.

I wasn't able to find anything useful in either original, OR new Disney Junior, novelizations.